# Required methods when inheriting from SequenceType

Tags: swift2

I'm looking at the protocol declaration for `SequenceType` and I'd like to know how one would understand that `generate` is the only function a class that derives from `SequenceType` should implement.

```
public protocol SequenceType {
    /// A type that provides the *sequence*'s iteration interface and
    /// encapsulates its iteration state.
    typealias Generator : GeneratorType
    /// A type that represents a subsequence of some of the elements.
    typealias SubSequence
    /// Return a *generator* over the elements of this *sequence*.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(1).
    @warn_unused_result
    public func generate() -> Self.Generator
    /// Return a value less than or equal to the number of elements in
    /// `self`, **nondestructively**.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(N).
    @warn_unused_result
    public func underestimateCount() -> Int
    /// Return an `Array` containing the results of mapping `transform`
    /// over `self`.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(N).
    @warn_unused_result
    @rethrows public func map<T>(@noescape transform: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

I implemented a custom class that derives from `SequenceType` and before I added support for generate, I got the following error:

> Type 'MySequenceClass' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Looking at the header declaration, I would assume that I have to implement all of the methods of this protocol but clearly I don't. What's the trick to reading these header docs?